# Consumir API com parâmetros obrigatórios

Tags: http, restful, http-request

se eu tenho uma API que requer dois parâmetros obrigatórios pra ser consumida, como devo inseri-los numa requisição $http?

```
self.buscaPrestadores = function()
{  
    $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: self.urlPrestadores,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            data: {'parametro1':abc,'parametro2':abc }
    }).then(function(resposta) { 
         var json = {};
         json = resposta.data.data;
         console.log(json);
    })
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quanto tento consumir a API da a mensagem abaixo no guia desenvolvedor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual o problema? `data: {uf: 'sp', id_especialidade: 1 }` não funciona?

Comment: Sim, tentei. Dessa forma: data: {uf:'ES',id_especialidade: 0001 }
Continua acusando erro do código do estado, que precisa ser com caracteres maiúsculos. Por isso me questionei se estava fazendo da forma correta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido:

Parametros GET são enviados via string na url logo precisa enviar como parâmetro direto na url, no caso do $http, o nome da estrutura é params e não data!